What makes dopaminergic neurons fire when maintaining base dopamine levels?
Are they signaled by other action potentials? Other neurotransmitters? Do they just fire on their own? If not triggered by an external stimulus, why does depolarization make them fire more frequently?

It would be helpful to provide some context for your question. What are you reading and where to trigger this question?

I am working on a pharmacology project that provides estimations for the physiological effects of different drugs based on their mechanism of action. I am aware that depolarization of dopaminergic neurons through means such as GABA inhibiton or nAChR agonism makes them fire more frequently, I just don't understand why.

Why would GABA inhibition depolarize a neuron or make it fire more frequently?

Is that not what GABA does? As far as I know, GABA makes the membrane potential of a neuron more negative, so that it does not reach its action potential threshold as easily, and inhibition of GABA makes affected neurons less negative and increases the frequency of action potentials.

I see. When someone says "GABA inhibition" I would assume they mean "inhibition mediated by the neurotransmitter GABA". If you mean inhibition of GABAergic neurons, you should be explicit about that or talk about "disinhibition". If you mean blocking GABA at the neurotransmitter receptor level this is not "inhibition" but "antagonism".

That's true, but disinhibition of dopaminergic neurons could be mediated by GABA receptor antagonism or inhibition of GABA release in the first place (which is what I intended to say and should have specified earlier).

Do you want to [edit] the question to add that and any research you've looked at in trying to find an answer to this as comments are intended to be temporary only.

The brain is very "noisy". Neurons in an actual brain don't just sit around waiting for an external stimulus. The "resting potential" of a neuron in a dish is not very representative of the membrane potential of a neuron in vivo.
There is a lot of debate about what "noise" really is, though. Is it actually "noise" in an intrinsic sense? How much of it is ongoing active brain activity? Given that it isn't as if a person sitting in a chair staring at a black screen has nothing going on in their minds, why should we expect there is nothing going on in their brain?
Practically, from an experimenter's perspective, noise is just "The part I didn't do." Baseline is just "in the absence of some intervention I might do later". We don't shut down the brain to measure a baseline.
Here are some reviews about noise in the brain, this list is not at all comprehensive:
Stein, R. B., Gossen, E. R., & Jones, K. E. (2005). Neuronal variability: noise or part of the signal?. Nature Reviews Neuroscience, 6(5), 389-397.
Faisal, A. A., Selen, L. P., & Wolpert, D. M. (2008). Noise in the nervous system. Nature reviews neuroscience, 9(4), 292-303.
Destexhe, A., & Rudolph-Lilith, M. (2012). Neuronal noise (Vol. 8). Springer Science & Business Media.
Uddin, L. Q. (2020). Bring the noise: reconceptualizing spontaneous neural activity. Trends in Cognitive Sciences, 24(9), 734-746.

If not triggered by an external stimulus, why does depolarization make them fire more frequently?

Imagine you had the membrane potential of any neuron, dopaminergic or not, where the membrane potential reflects the sum of all inputs to that cell, with some spikes occurring at baseline. There are also going to be a lot of times (most of the time) where there is no spike at all. If you were to depolarize the cell, it will fire at some of those other times as well. That's an increase in firing rate.
